# Not able to select value from the select list and grid in oracle apex application

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am trying to automate my oracle apex based web application but i am not able to select any value from the select list where i want to select customers as well as from the grid from which i select items.
Problem is that with the help of xpath it only opens up the list of customers but not select that particular value from the list.

My Source code is as below

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Inventory")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sale Order")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS );
driver.findElement(By.id("Create")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"P191_ORDER_TYPE\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"P191_SUPPLIER_CODE_CONTAINER\"]/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/span")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS );

Select oselect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("select2-P191_SUPPLIER_CODE-container")));
oselect.selectByVisibleText("K. K. INDUSTRIES RR-00004");
driver.findElement(By.id("item_name")).click();
```

Comment: please Share your HTML Dom code

Comment: Also, please share your actual automation test code. What programming language are you using? The more info you provide, the easier it is for the community to help.